# Subset of lines that are within polygon in R

Tags: r, overlapping-features

I have a large `SpatialLinesDataFrame` (~23000 features) and a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` (8 features). I want to make 8 new variables, each with the lines that are on the same locations as the polygons. This should be easy, but I can't find the right way.

I tried the `sp::over` method, but it returns the error: `Don't Kont how to get path data from object of class data.frame`. I assume that this is because in the help section there is not a method where `x = SpatialLinesDataFrame` and `y = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, please ask a good question by providing some example data as below:

```
library(raster)
cds <- rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45))
lines <- spLines(cds, cds-20, cds+20, attr=data.frame(Lid=1:3))

p1 <- rbind(c(180,20), c(140,-55), c(10, 0), c(140,60), c(180,20))
p2 <- rbind(c(-10,0), c(-140,-60), c(-160,0), c(-140,55), c(-10,0))
pols <- spPolygons(p1, p2, attr=data.frame(Pid=1:2))

plot(pols)
lines(lines, col='blue')
```

Now you can do

```
x <- intersect(lines, pols)
```

You can use subsetting to get the lines that match a specific polygon

```
LP1 <- x[x$Pid == 1, ]
```

Perhaps wrapped in a `lapply` to get a list

```
p <- lapply(1:length(pols), function(i) x[x$Pid == i, ])
```